# What's the difference between readAsStringAsync() and writeAsStringAsync() FileSystem in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a function that generates a PDF file and i want to get the Uri's of the file to stoke it locally and then send it as an attachment with `MailComposer`. I want to know what's the difference between `readAsStringAsync()` and `writeAsStringAsync()` in [FileSystem](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#methods)?

Answer (score 0):

Both `readAsStringAsync()` and `writeAsStringAsync()` are functions of `Expo FileSystem`.

But the difference is `readAsStringAsync()` used to read a local files of the device. While `writeAsStringAsync()` is used to write onto a local file or create a file (if the named file does not exist on the location)

Answer (score 0):

According to Expo Documentation documentation 
[FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemwriteasstringasyncfileuri-contents-options):
"Write the entire contents of a file as a string."

[FileSystem.readAsStringAsync](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreadasstringasyncfileuri-options):
"Read the entire contents of a file as a string. Binary will be returned in raw format, you will need to append data:image/png;base64, to use it as Base64."